# Partition Parquet files on Azure Blob (pyarrow)

Tags: azure-blob-storage, parquet, pyarrow

I have been manually partitioning files with pandas (creating an index or multi-index and then writing a separate parquet file for each index in a loop) to Azure Blob.

However, when reading the docs for pyarrow, I see that it is possible to create a 'dataset' which includes a folder structure for partitioned data.  https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

The example for the Monthly / daily folder is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

```
dataset_name/
  year=2007/
    month=01/
       0.parq
       1.parq
       ...
    month=02/
       0.parq
       1.parq
       ...
    month=03/
    ...
  year=2008/
    month=01/
    ...



fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host, port, user=user, kerb_ticket=ticket_cache_path)
pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path='dataset_name',
                    partition_cols=['one', 'two'], filesystem=fs)
```

Can I do this with Azure Blob (or Minio which uses S3 and wraps over my Azure Blob storage)? My ultimate goal is to only read files which make sense for my 'query'.

Comment: What's your environment to run your Python script using pyarrow? Such as LInux on Azure VM or on local?

Comment: Linux on an Azure VM (I installed all software myself though - everything is mostly docker containers at this point using some popular images). Python is current from the Jupyterhub image

Answer (score 4):

Just per my experience and based on your current environment Linux on Azure VM, I think there are two solutions can read partition parquet files from Azure Storage.

1. Follow the section [`Reading a Parquet File from Azure Blob storage`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-a-parquet-file-from-azure-blob-storage) of the document `Reading and Writing the Apache Parquet Format` of `pyarrow`, manually to list the blob names with the prefix like `dataset_name` using the API [`list_blob_names(container_name, prefix=None, num_results=None, include=None, delimiter=None, marker=None, timeout=None)`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.list_blob_names) of Azure Storgae SDK for Python as the figure below, then to read these blobs one by one like the sample code to dataframes, finally to [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-objects) these dataframes to a single one.

   [image]
2. Try to use [`Azure/azure-storage-fuse`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse) to mount a container of Azure Blob Storage to your Linux filesystem, then you just need to follow the document section [`Reading from Partitioned Datasets`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-from-partitioned-datasets) to read the Partitioned Dataset locally from Azure Blob Storage.